# How can I make spellchecking work for additionally installed languages in Firefox and Evolution?

Tags: gnome, firefox, evolution, ubuntu-gnome, language-support

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 LTS. During installation, I selected German as my language and Europe/Tallinn as my time zone. As a result, support for German, English, and Estonian was installed. At least, when I go to GNOME Settings » Region and Language » Language, I see German, several variants of English, and Estonian in the list.

Unfortunately, it seems that support for Estonian is not fully installed. Neither in Firefox nor in Evolution, I can select Estonian as the spell checking language. I tried to install language support for Estonian via GNOME Settings, but GNOME Settings obviously considered Estonian language support as already installed, as witnessed by Estonian being in the abovementioned list.

I could try to install language packages manually via `apt-get`. However, I do not want to do this, as I guess this might confuse GNOME Settings.

How can I safely install support for Estonian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal window and run this command:

```
sudo apt install $(check-language-support)
```

Based on your description, that ought to be it.

Comment: Wow, just running `check-language-support` showed 18 packages (not only related to Estonian), which all had not been installed by the Ubuntu GNOME installer. I have run the command you suggested, and spell checking works perfectly now. ☺

Comment: @WolfgangJeltsch: Great that it fixed it. Reminded me about [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1294858).

Answer (score 1):

To install the spellcheck:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aspell-et myspell-et
```

There is no reason why this would confuse Gnome Settings.

Comment: How does GNOME Settings determine whether support for a particular language is installed? Does it maintain a list of languages separate from the list of installed Ubuntu (*.deb) packages? If this is the case, then manually installing packages via `apt-get` could possibly confuse GNOME Settings, as the installation of these packages might not update the list maintained by GNOME Settings.

Comment: @WolfgangJeltsch: This is somewhat complex, and without being sure, I suspect that the presence of folders in `/usr/share/locale-langpack` has something to do with it. Probably (and personally I blame the installer from doing the wrong thing) the complete English and Estonian language support was not in place to start with. You can fix that with the command I provided in my answer. (But installing some of the affected packages manually, as Bruni suggested, cannot hurt.)

Comment: @WolfgangJeltsch If what you are missing is spellcheck, than the spelling dictionaries should suffice irrespective of whether the language support is installed or not. Removing those packages is in any case not difficult. I guess that GNOME Settings checks if the estonian suport metapackage is installed or not.